# Keras ModelCheckpoint is introducing additional layers while saving model

Tags: python, python-3.x, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to save a model using ModelCheckpoint in Keras. I save the model using the following code snippet.

```
model = load_vgg()
parallel_model = keras.utils.multi_gpu_model(model_1, gpus=2)
parallel_model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", metrics=['accuracy'], optimizer=Adam())
early_stopping = EarlyStopping(monitor='val_loss', min_delta=0, patience=5, verbose=1, mode='min')
checkpoint = ModelCheckpoint(os.path.join(ouput_dir, "model.h5"), monitor='val_loss', verbose=1, save_best_only=True, mode='auto')
history = parallel_model.fit_generator(train_gen, steps_per_epoch=math.ceil(num_train_samples / batch_size), validation_data=val_gen, validation_steps=math.ceil(num_val_samples / batch_size), epochs=200, verbose=1, class_weight=class_weights, callbacks=[checkpoint, early_stopping])
model.save(os.path.join(ouput_dir, 'model_2.h5'))
```

Model is defined using the following code:

```
def load_vgg(in_shape=(x, y), n_classes=1, n_stages_per_blocks=[2, 2, 2, 2, 2]):
  in_layer = keras.layers.Input(in_shape)
  block1 = _block(in_layer, 64, n_stages_per_blocks[0])
  pool1 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(block1)
  block2 = _block(pool1, 128, n_stages_per_blocks[1])
  pool2 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(block2)
  block3 = _block(pool2, 256, n_stages_per_blocks[2])
  pool3 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(block3)
  block4 = _block(pool3, 512, n_stages_per_blocks[3])
  pool4 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(block4)
  block5 = _block(pool4, 512, n_stages_per_blocks[4])
  pool5 = keras.layers.MaxPool1D()(block5)
  flattened = keras.layers.Flatten()(pool5)
  dense1 = keras.layers.Dense(2048, activation='relu')(flattened)
  dense2 = keras.layers.Dense(1024, activation='relu')(dense1)
  preds = keras.layers.Dense(n_classes, activation='sigmoid')(dense2)
  model = keras.models.Model(in_layer, preds)
  model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['accuracy'])
  return model

convBlock = partial(keras.layers.Conv1D, kernel_size=3, strides=1, padding='same', activation='relu')

def _block(in_tensor, filters, n_convs):
  conv_block = in_tensor
  for _ in range(n_convs):
    conv_block = convBlock(filters=filters)(conv_block)
  return conv_block
```

Problem: When we load the model saved using ModelCheckpoint and the model saved directly using save function, they provide us with the different model summaries.

Summary of the model saved using ModelCheckpoint: 
[image: 1]]
Summary of the model saved using the model's save function:
[image: 2]]

Why the ModelCheckpoint is introducing three additional layers and moving the model into the model_1 layer? What changes do I have to make sure the model saved by the ModelCheckpoint has the same structure as the one obtained by using the save function? Any help will be much appreciated. Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Keras documentation:

> To save the multi-gpu model, use `.save(fname)` or `.save_weights(fname)`
>   with the template model (the argument you passed to multi_gpu_model),
>   rather than the model returned by multi_gpu_model.

When we use ModelCheckpoint, the same problem occurs. The callback is called on the GPU model, which is not correct.

There are two solutions: 1) you implement a version of ModelCheckpoint where you pass the template model as an argument (code provided below), or 2) you following this [suggestion](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2436#issuecomment-354882296)
implement a class that ensures that any call to save function will use the template model.

ModelCheckpoint implementation for the multi_gpu_model:

```
import keras
import numpy as np 
import warnings

class ModelCheckpoint(keras.callbacks.Callback):

    def __init__(self, filepath, ser_model, monitor='val_loss', verbose=0,
                 save_best_only=False, save_weights_only=False,
                 mode='auto', period=1):
        super(ModelCheckpoint, self).__init__()
        self.monitor = monitor
        self.verbose = verbose
        self.filepath = filepath
        self.save_best_only = save_best_only
        self.save_weights_only = save_weights_only
        self.period = period
        self.epochs_since_last_save = 0
        self.ser_model = ser_model

        if mode not in ['auto', 'min', 'max']:
            warnings.warn('ModelCheckpoint mode %s is unknown, '
                          'fallback to auto mode.' % (mode),
                          RuntimeWarning)
            mode = 'auto'

        if mode == 'min':
            self.monitor_op = np.less
            self.best = np.Inf
        elif mode == 'max':
            self.monitor_op = np.greater
            self.best = -np.Inf
        else:
            if 'acc' in self.monitor or self.monitor.startswith('fmeasure'):
                self.monitor_op = np.greater
                self.best = -np.Inf
            else:
                self.monitor_op = np.less
                self.best = np.Inf

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs=None):
        logs = logs or {}
        self.epochs_since_last_save += 1
        if self.epochs_since_last_save >= self.period:
            self.epochs_since_last_save = 0
            filepath = self.filepath.format(epoch=epoch + 1, **logs)
            if self.save_best_only:
                current = logs.get(self.monitor)
                if current is None:
                    warnings.warn('Can save best model only with %s available, '
                                  'skipping.' % (self.monitor), RuntimeWarning)
                else:
                    if self.monitor_op(current, self.best):
                        if self.verbose > 0:
                            print('\nEpoch %05d: %s improved from %0.5f to %0.5f,'
                                  ' saving model to %s'
                                  % (epoch + 1, self.monitor, self.best,
                                     current, filepath))
                        self.best = current
                        if self.save_weights_only:
                            self.ser_model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
                        else:
                            self.ser_model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
                    else:
                        if self.verbose > 0:
                            print('\nEpoch %05d: %s did not improve from %0.5f' %
                                  (epoch + 1, self.monitor, self.best))
            else:
                if self.verbose > 0:
                    print('\nEpoch %05d: saving model to %s' % (epoch + 1, filepath))
                if self.save_weights_only:
                    self.ser_model.save_weights(filepath, overwrite=True)
                else:
                    self.ser_model.save(filepath, overwrite=True)
```

Feel free to give any comments and suggestions you have!